# Network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: database

I have a task to monitor the performance of database. I have downloaded one tool to monitor the server database named MyORA. I encounter problem when trying to make a new connection of database with the tool. It keep showing "Network adapter could not establish the connection" error when I press the connect button. Have anyone experienced using this tool or anyone have any idea to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]Here is the screenshot of the tool and error

Answer (score 1):

Verify following items.

[1] Check that you are using the correct URL

[2] Telnet your IP on port 1521

[3] Check port number or IP address (or DNS host name)  used

[4] The listener is not configured properly

[5] The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

Comment: Where can i find the listener service on my windows? and how to configure the listener properly?

Comment: 1] $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Follow URL, screenshot is given for listener.ora, make necessary changes in file and restart servcie
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm